# Como acceder a un archivo desde otro proyecto Laravel

Tags: laravel, archivo, laravel-8, upload, download

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo 2 proyectos

1. Proyecto 1: subo información con archivos adjuntos.
2. Proyecto 2:    visualizo información y descarga de archivos.

El problema que tengo es como descargar los archivos en el proyecto 2, dado que los archivos se guardan en la carpeta proyecto1/public/Documentos en el proyecto 1, y no se como acceder a esa carpeta desde el proyecto 2.

Ambos proyectos trabajan con la misma base de datos, la tabla documento tiene la siguiente información Documento(id, nombre_documento, id_solicitud)
Así guardo los documentos en el proyecto 1

```
$documentos = $request->file('documentos');
    foreach($documentos as $documento){
        $nombreDoc = $documento->getClientOriginalName();

        $doc = new Documento;
        $doc->nombreDocumento = $nombreDoc;
        $doc->id_solicitud = $solicitud->id_solicitud;
        $documento->move(public_path().'/Documentos/',$nombreDoc);
        $doc->save();
    }
```

Comment: Si los archivos están en un subdirectorio de la carpeta `proyecto1/public/` son accesibles públicamente por su url. Podrías simplemente poner un enlace a la url del proyecto1 para descargarlo. Por ejemplo `<a href="http://proyecto1.com/Documentos/archivo_x.pdf">Descargar archivo_x</a>`

Comment: Y si quieres accederlos desde el lado del servidor (por ejemplo para enumerarlos con una tarea del scheduler, aunque suena irrelevante) probablemente sea más eficiente dejar un link simbólico al proyecto 1 en la carpeta storage del proyecto 2, para no estar adivinando en el árbol de directorios cuántos tienes que retroceder